# Compare pairs of values within a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
points = [(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 7), (1, -3), (3, -2), (4, 5),
          (3, 2), (5, 7), (-5, 7), (2, 2), (-4, 5), (0, -2),
          (-4, 7), (-1, 3), (-3, 2), (-4, -5), (-3, 2),
          (5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2), (9, 9), (-8, -9)]

equal_values = 0
```

I'd like to count how many times in this list each pair of values are equal e.g. `(2, 2)`. How can I define that condition in an if statement?

```
if ??? in points:

    equal_values +=1
```

Comment: What have you tried on your own? Please Show your code. See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it quickly by this:

```
len([i for i in points if i[0]==i[1]])
```

Or with a common for loop combined with if statement, like below:

```
equal_values = 0
for i in points:
    if i[0]==i[1]:
        equal_points+=1
```

The output is 3 for both ways, for your given list

Comment: While this might answer the question, providing details as to how to reached the conclusion and your thought process will surely help the fellow asker. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot for answering my question

Comment: Great! Can you please accept one of the answers, if your problem was resolved? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You want this ?

```
points = [(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 7), (1, -3), (3, -2), (4, 5),
          (3, 2), (5, 7), (-5, 7), (2, 2), (-4, 5), (0, -2),
          (-4, 7), (-1, 3), (-3, 2), (-4, -5), (-3, 2),
          (5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2), (9, 9), (-8, -9)]

print(points.count((2, 2)))
```

To count the number of the `(2, 2)` occurence in your list ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I want to count the occurence that the first value = the second. This happens with (2, 2) but also a ocuple more times eg (9, 9)

Comment: oh okay so the best format is `len([i for i in points if i[0]==i[1]])`

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
equal = [i for i in points if i[0] == i[1]]
```

then get the count (length of the list):

```
len(equal)
```

how does that work?

- it loops through the elements in points and checks if the `0th` and the `1st` index's are equal
- it appends that item to a list if it is equal
- we get the count of equal pairs by checking the **length** of the list

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. That worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for x in points:
  m = list(iterable(x))
  if len(set(m)) == 1:
    equal_values += 1
```

Comment: I'm getting error: iterable not defined. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious!